# setTimeout not working in Greasemonkey user script when JS disabled in browser

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, settimeout

I'm working on a project that requires my user script be run on pages as they are rendered without executing any of the page's JavaScript. That is to say, we need to browse with JavaScript disabled.

I've encountered a problem though when I try to delay execution of a function within my script. Whenever I make a call to `window.setTimeout`, the function I pass in never gets executed.

I think maybe this function is actually getting called on `unsafeWindow` instead of window. Is there any workaround for this?

I should mention that calls to `setTimeout` work fine when JavaScript is enabled and everything else in my script is working fine without enabling JavaScript.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know, but perhaps the NoScript extension could do you some help: http://noscript.net/

Comment: NoScript looks promising.  I'll look into it more.  I haven't got time to test atm, but I guess if I set localhost as the only trusted site then I should get the behavior I'm looking for...  Thanks trinithis!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though Greasemonkey JavaScript runs with elevated privileges, as Pointy said, `setTimeout` functions are appended to the page's JavaScript space -- wrapped in a closure as needed.   (In normal operation, the Greasemonkey instance is often gone by the time any timers, it has set, fire.)

So, if the page's main JavaScript is disabled, the timer will never run.

Possible workarounds:

- Use `GM_xmlhttpRequest` as a crude delay.  You can setup a page that deliberately draws out its response.  So code like:

  ```
  GM_xmlhttpRequest
  (
      {
          method: "GET",
          url:    "http://YourTestServer.com/DelayService.php?Seconds=2",
          onload: function (response) {YourDelayedFunctionHere (); }
      }
  );
  ```

  Would call a utility page that you set up to do the delay for you.
- Use NoScript to disable all of the page's JavaScript except for the main page.   For example, for page, ***YourSite.com/testpage.htm***, which includes scripts from, say, ***SpamGenerator.net**...  Allow scripts from ***YourSite.com*** but block them from ***SpamGenerator.net***.

Comment: NoScript as it turns out doesn't work for me, since I need to disable JavaScript from the main page as well as from any other sources that aren't my user script.  The XMLhttpRequest on the other hand works beautifully (even though it's a total hack).

Thanks for the insight, Brock!

Answer (score 2):

The `window` reference is still the page's `window`, just wrapped in the sandbox wrapper thing. When you call `setTimeout` on it you're still setting up something to be run by the page. I suppose that it must be the case that the browser won't fire those timeout events at all (or will just ignore the events) when Javascript is disabled.

Comment: But since it's wrapped up, it isn't *really* the page's window, right?  Greasemonkey gets to define its behavior, instead of the page being allowed to do this.  I'm wondering if GM maybe just punts on the function call and allows the original window (ie. unsafeWindow) to deal with it. (Edit: In the end, my understanding is the same as yours.  The call gets set up and ignored.  Now I'm just wondering if there's any way around this.  Maybe some way to delay function execution outside of using window object...?)

Comment: Well Greasemonkey might not get a say in the matter if the browser thinks that it shouldn't run any Javascript event handlers. I have not found any explicit documentation that says what happens when Javascript is disabled on a page. Obviously the "native" event handling still works - you can still submit forms by clicking "submit" buttons for example, and checkboxes and radio buttons work.

Answer (score 0):

this can be patched like this:

You can say NO to NoScript + setTimeout = failed

In `greasemonkey.js`: find [ injectScripts ]: function..... add our GM-api.....

Add this code:

```
sandbox.setTimeOut = function (callback, timeout, p1,p2,p3/*....*/){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,2);
    return  sandbox.window.setTimeout(function(){
        return callback.apply(sandbox, args);
    } ,timeout);
}
```

or

```
sandbox.setInterval = function (callback, timeout, p1,p2,p3/*....*/){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,2);
    return sandbox.window.setInterval(function(){
        return callback.apply(sandbox, args);
    } ,timeout);
}
```

This code is working fine, I have used it since May 2010.

In `user.js` you can test it like this:

```
setTimeout(alert,1000, 'i am happy');
var loopid = setInterval(alert, 1000, 'I am happy again');
setTimeout(clearInterval, 5000, loopid);

var j=300;
for(;~j;j--){ //running perfectly!
    setTimeout(alert, 1000+20*j, 'I am happy' )
}
```

### Solution 2

```
sandbox.kk_setTimeout = function (func, timeout, repeat_type, p1,p2,p3/*....*/){
    var callback = { k100: sandbox };
    var args = Array.slice.call(arguments,3);

    // repeat_type:  0=once  1=repeatng, after fired stopped    2=always repeat
    if(repeat_type!=2){
        callback.notify = function (timer){ func.apply(this.k100,args); }
        var timerCC = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/timer;1", "nsITimer", 'initWithCallback');
        var R = repeat_type?1:0;
    } else {
        callback.observe = function (subject, topic, data) { func.call(this.k100); };
        var timerCC = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/timer;1", "nsITimer", 'init'); 
        var R = 2; 
    }
    return new timerCC(callback, timeout, R);
}

// now have to test it:

var test100 = kk_setTimeout(alert, 1000, 0, 'i am timer');  //running = setTimeout
var test100 = kk_setTimeout(alert, 1000, 2, 'i am timer');  //running = setInterval
test100.cancal() ;   //clear it by cancel() method

kk_setTimeout(alert, 1000+20*j, 2, 'i am happy' );
var j=300;
for(;~j;j--){
    kk_setTimeout(alert, 1000+20*j, 0, 'i am happy 2' );
}

//bug:
//this solution 2 running after about 3-8 times differently stop, why bug ? i don't know.
// you will fail to use many times(over 3-8 time) kk_timeout(); or using repeat_type = 2 after fired 3-8 times timeout
//or running total time max about 20-30 seconds stop 
//--- this maybe stop by option in about:config -- about [max javascript run time]
```

china-kkmove patched

---

*edit to add…*

Sorry everyone,

There are still a few patches to the code that I forgot to write:

```
sandbox.window = sandbox._proto_; // add this line also to the solution 1#
```

This error just came to my mind this morning.

Comment: Doesn't this hack get overwritten every time the GM add-on updates?  Also, this solution is not portable -- makes it much harder to share the user's script.